# Overriding the 'not' operator in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading, operators

I cannot find the method corresponding to `not x` operator. There is one for *and*, *or*, and *xor*, though. Where is it?

*[3. Data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)*

Comment: [__not__](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__not__) . Return the outcome of not obj. (Note that there is no __not__() method for object instances; only the interpreter core defines this operation. The result is affected by the __nonzero__() and __len__() methods.)

Comment: [`operator.__not__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__not__) can be found in the standard library (and more!). As already pointed out in some answers it depends on `__bool__` and `__len__`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are no hooks for `and` or `or` operators, no (as they short-circuit), and there is no `xor` operator in Python. The `__and__` and `__or__` are for the [*bitwise* `&` and `|` operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations), respectively. The equivalent bitwise operator for `not` is `~` (inversion), which is handled by the [`__invert__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__), while [`__xor__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__xor__) covers the `^` bitwise operator.

`not` operates on the [*truth-value* of an object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). If you have a container, give it a [`__len__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), if not give it a [`__bool__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__). Either one is consulted to determine if an object should be considered 'true'; `not` inverts the result of that test.

So if `__bool__` returns `True` or `__len__` returns an integer other than `0`, `not` will invert that to `False`, otherwise `not` produces `True`. Note that you can't make `not` return anything else but a boolean value!

From the documentation for `__bool__`:

> `__bool__`
>   Called to implement truth value testing and the built-in operation `bool()`; should return `False` or `True`. When this method is not defined, `__len__()` is called, if it is defined, and the object is considered true if its result is nonzero. If a class defines neither `__len__()` nor `__bool__()`, all its instances are considered true.>

and for the [`not` expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. **User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a `__bool__()` method.**
>
> The operator `not` yields `True` if its argument is false, `False` otherwise.

*bold emphasis mine*.

Answer (score 4):

> There is one for *and*, *or*, and *xor*, though

The methods you're looking at are for *bitwise* `&`, `|`, and `^`, not `and`, `or`, or `xor` (which isn't even a Python operator).

`not` cannot be overloaded, just like `and` and `or` can't be overloaded. Bitwise `~` can be overloaded, though; that's `__invert__`.

If you're in a situation where you wish you could overload `not`, you'll either have to make do with overloading `~` instead, or you'll have to write your own `logical_not` function and use that instead of the `not` operator.

Comment: `not` can be influenced though, via `__bool__`. Just return the inverse. `and` and `or` can't be overridden because they short-circuit, but that's not the case for `not`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It can be influenced though `__bool__`, and if what you really want is to control whether your object is considered true or false, `__bool__` is what you should use, but if you want `not` to build a `Not` node of an expression tree or an array of inverted booleans, or if you want `not NULL` to be `NULL` for your custom `NULL` object, `__bool__` won't help you,

Comment: Nope, as covered in my answer: *Note that you can't make `not` return anything else but a boolean value!*.